# While breakpoint-modified in Eclipse gdb traces, I am getting this error for dprintf: "Error in re-setting breakpoint 3: Format string required"

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

> While inserting the dprintf, format string is present but vanishes
>   when the breakpoint remains pending as the shared library, where
>   breakpoint is inserted is not loaded yet. Hence when dprintf
>   breakpoint is modified, it could not find the format string parameter
>   resulting to error: "Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Format string required\n". In the gdb traces below,
>   script parameter is missing for dprintf breakpoint when modified.

## *gdb-traces*

```
850,705 2-list-thread-groups
850,715 2^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process"}]
850,755 3-gdb-version
850,815 (gdb) 
850,815 ~"GNU gdb (Linaro GDB) 7.8-2014.09\n"
850,835 ~"Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.\n"
850,835 ~"License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>\nThis is fre\
e software: you are free to change and redistribute it.\nThere is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitt\
ed by law.  Type \"show copying\"\nand \"show warranty\" for details.\n"
850,835 ~"This GDB was configured as \"--host=i586-mingw32msvc --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf\".\nType\
 \"show configuration\" for configuration details."
850,835 ~"\nFor bug reporting instructions, please see:\n"
850,835 ~"<http://bugs.linaro.org>.\n"
850,835 ~"Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:\n<http://www.gnu.org/soft\
ware/gdb/documentation/>.\n"
850,835 ~"For help, type \"help\".\n"
850,835 ~"Type \"apropos word\" to search for commands related to \"word\".\n"
850,835 3^done
850,835 (gdb) 
850,895 4-environment-cd D:/Workspace/Oxygen/runtime-DevWS/testOne
850,905 4^done
850,905 (gdb) 
850,945 5-gdb-set breakpoint pending on
850,946 5^done
850,946 (gdb) 
850,976 6-gdb-set detach-on-fork on
850,986 6^done
850,986 (gdb) 
851,006 7-enable-pretty-printing
851,016 7^done
851,016 (gdb) 
851,026 8-gdb-set python print-stack none
851,036 8^done
851,036 (gdb) 
851,046 9-gdb-set print object on
851,056 9^done
851,056 (gdb) 
851,076 10-gdb-set print sevenbit-strings on
851,086 10^done
851,086 (gdb) 
851,116 11-gdb-set host-charset UTF-8
851,126 11^error,msg="Undefined item: \"UTF-8\"."
851,126 (gdb) 
851,166 12-gdb-set target-charset WINDOWS-1252
851,176 12^error,msg="Undefined item: \"WINDOWS-1252\"."
851,176 (gdb) 
851,176 13-gdb-set target-wide-charset UTF-16
851,186 13^error,msg="Undefined item: \"UTF-16\"."
851,186 (gdb) 
851,206 14-gdb-set auto-solib-add on
851,216 14^done
851,216 (gdb) 
851,226 15-target-select extended-remote 192.168.7.2:1234
851,438 15^connected
851,438 (gdb) 
851,458 16-file-symbol-file D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\ABC
851,728 16^done
851,728 (gdb) 
851,900 17-target-attach --thread-group i1 248
851,930 =thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="248"
851,930 =thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"
851,970 18-list-thread-groups
851,980 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
851,990 17^done
851,990 =thread-created,id="2",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.250]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="3",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.291]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="4",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.292]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="5",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.293]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="6",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.294]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="7",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.295]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="8",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.297]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="9",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.298]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="10",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.299]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="11",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.300]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="12",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.301]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="13",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.302]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="14",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.303]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="15",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.304]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="16",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.305]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="17",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.306]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="18",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.307]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="19",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.308]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="20",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.309]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="21",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.310]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="22",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.311]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="23",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.312]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="24",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.313]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="25",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.314]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="26",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.315]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="27",group-id="i1"
851,990 ~"[New Thread 248.316]\n"
851,990 =thread-created,id="28",group-id="i1"
851,991 ~"[New Thread 248.317]\n"
851,991 =thread-created,id="29",group-id="i1"
851,991 ~"[New Thread 248.318]\n"
852,008 18^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process",pid="248",cores=["0","1"]}]
852,008 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
852,008 ~"0x76900924 in ?? ()\n"
852,008 *stopped,frame={addr="0x76900924",func="??",args=[]},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",cor\
e="0"
852,008 (gdb) 
852,159 19-gdb-show --thread-group i1 language
852,189 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,189 19^done,value="auto"
852,189 =thread-selected,id="29"
852,189 (gdb) 
852,289 20-gdb-set --thread-group i1 language c
852,299 20^done
852,299 (gdb) 
852,299 21-list-thread-groups i1
852,379 22-interpreter-exec --thread-group i1 console "p/x (char)-1"
852,559 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,609 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,629 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,679 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,869 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,879 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,949 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
852,999 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
853,019 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
853,019 21^done
853,039 (gdb) 
853,039 ~"$1 = 0xff\n"
853,039 22^done
853,039 (gdb) 
853,099 23-data-evaluate-expression --thread-group i1 "sizeof (void*)"
853,109 23^done,value="4"
853,109 (gdb) 
853,159 24-stack-info-depth --thread 1 11
853,159 25-gdb-set --thread-group i1 language auto
853,189 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
853,209 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
853,229 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
853,229 24^done,depth="2"
853,229 (gdb) 
853,269 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x80\n"
853,269 25^done
853,269 =thread-selected,id="29"
853,269 (gdb) 
853,339 26-interpreter-exec --thread-group i1 console "show endian"
853,349 ~"The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)\n"
853,349 26^done
853,349 (gdb) 
853,839 27-dprintf-insert -f D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c:11 "Hit line %\
d of D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c\n" 11
853,839 28-break-insert -f D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c:9
853,839 29-dprintf-insert -f D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c:17 "Hit line %\
d of D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c\n" 17
853,839 30-break-insert -f D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c:15
853,849 &"No source file named D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c.\n\
"
853,849 27^done,bkpt={number="1",type="dprintf",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="<PENDING>",pending="D:\
\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:11",times="0",original-location="D:\
\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:11"}
853,849 (gdb) 
853,849 &"No source file named D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c.\n\
"
853,849 28^done,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="<PENDING>",pending=\
"D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:9",times="0",original-location="\
D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:9"}
853,849 (gdb) 
853,849 &"No source file named D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c.\n\
"
853,849 29^done,bkpt={number="3",type="dprintf",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="<PENDING>",pending="D:\
\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:17",times="0",original-location="D:\
\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:17"}
853,849 (gdb) 
853,849 &"No source file named D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c.\n\
"
853,849 30^done,bkpt={number="4",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="<PENDING>",pending=\
"D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:15",times="0",original-location=\
"D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:15"}
853,849 (gdb) 
853,919 32-stack-select-frame --thread 1 0
853,929 (gdb) 
853,949 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
853,949 32^done
853,949 (gdb) 
853,969 33-gdb-set solib-search-path C:\\myProject\\HW_Libraries_DEBUG;C:\\myProject\\lib;C:\
\\myProject\\usr\\lib
854,029 34-list-thread-groups --available
854,039 35-thread-info 1
854,429 36-stack-info-depth --thread 29 11
854,449 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
854,449 37-thread-info 2
854,659 33^done
854,659 (gdb) 
854,659 38-thread-info 3
854,659 39-thread-info 4
854,719 34^done
854,719 (gdb) 
854,729 40-thread-info 5
854,729 41-stack-list-frames --thread 1
854,759 35^done
854,759 (gdb) 
854,759 42-gdb-set dprintf-style call
854,759 43-list-thread-groups
855,430 36^done,depth="6"
855,430 (gdb) 
855,520 37^done
855,530 (gdb) 
855,530 44-thread-select 29
855,530 45-thread-info 29
855,600 38^done
855,600 (gdb) 
855,600 46-thread-info 24
855,600 47-thread-info 25
855,680 39^done
855,680 (gdb) 
855,680 48-thread-info 26
855,680 49-thread-info 27
855,748 40^done
855,748 (gdb) 
855,748 50-thread-info 28
855,748 51-thread-select 29
855,798 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
855,828 &"Cannot access memory at address 0x0\n"
855,828 41^done
855,828 (gdb) 
855,828 42^done
855,828 (gdb) 
855,918 43^done
855,918 (gdb) 
855,918 52source C:\\myProject\\.gdbinit
855,979 44^done
855,979 (gdb) 
856,019 45^done
856,019 (gdb) 
856,119 46^done
856,119 (gdb) 
856,219 47^done
856,219 (gdb) 
856,309 48^done
856,309 (gdb) 
856,409 49^done
856,409 (gdb) 
856,509 50^done
856,509 (gdb) 
856,539 51^done
856,539 (gdb) 
856,539 &"source C:\\\\myProject\\\\.gdbinit\n"
856,539 52^done
856,539 (gdb) 
856,549 53-gdb-set target-async off
856,559 53^error,msg="Cannot change this setting while the inferior is running."
856,559 (gdb) 
856,589 54-stack-select-frame --thread 1 0
856,639 54^done
856,639 (gdb) 
862,956 55-thread-info 6
862,956 56-thread-info 7
862,956 57-thread-info 8
862,956 58-thread-info 9
862,956 59-thread-info 10
862,956 60-stack-list-locals --thread 1 --frame 0 1
863,076 55^done
863,076 (gdb) 
863,176 56^done
863,176 (gdb) 
863,287 57^done
863,287 (gdb) 
863,387 58^done
863,387 (gdb) 
863,487 59^done
863,487 (gdb) 
863,487 60^done
863,487 (gdb) 
863,768 61-exec-continue --thread 1
863,820 61^running
863,820 *running,thread-id="all"
863,820 (gdb) 
863,940 62-thread-select 1
864,950 =library-loaded,id="/home/root/libtestOne.so",target-name="/home/root/libtestOne.so",host-na\
me="C:\\myProject\\HW_Libraries_DEBUG\\libtestOne.so",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
865,050 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="1",type="dprintf",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x625595e\
6",func="Hello",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOn\
e.c",line="11",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtim\
e-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:11"}
865,050 &"Error in re-setting breakpoint 1: Format string required\n"
865,050 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x6255\
95dc",func="Hello",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\tes\
tOne.c",line="9",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runt\
ime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:9"}
865,060 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="3",type="dprintf",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x6255960\
e",func="Hello1",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testO\
ne.c",line="17",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runti\
me-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:17"}
865,060 &"Error in re-setting breakpoint 3: Format string required\n"
865,060 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="4",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x6255\
9604",func="Hello1",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\te\
stOne.c",line="15",thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\ru\
ntime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:15"}
865,180 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x6255\
95dc",func="Hello",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\tes\
tOne.c",line="9",thread-groups=["i1"],times="1",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runt\
ime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:9"}
865,210 ~"\nBreakpoint "
865,210 ~"2, Hello () at ..\\testOne.c:9\n"
865,210 ~"9\t\tputs(\"Hello World\");\n"
865,210 *stopped,reason="breakpoint-hit",disp="keep",bkptno="2",frame={addr="0x625595dc",func="Hello\
",args=[],file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c",l\
ine="9"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",core="0"
865,210 (gdb) 
865,240 62^done,new-thread-id="1",frame={level="0",addr="0x625595dc",func="Hello",args=[],file="..\\\
testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c",line="9"}
865,240 (gdb) 
865,310 63-stack-info-depth --thread 1 11
865,610 63^done,depth="4"
865,610 (gdb) 
865,620 64-stack-select-frame --thread 1 0
865,630 65-list-thread-groups
865,630 66-thread-info 1
865,630 64^done
865,630 (gdb) 
865,680 67-stack-list-frames --thread 1
865,700 65^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process",pid="248",cores=["0","1"]}]
865,700 (gdb) 
865,700 68-stack-list-locals --thread 1 --frame 0 1
865,700 69-thread-info 2
865,740 66^done,threads=[{id="1",target-id="Thread 248.248",frame={level="0",addr="0x625595dc",func=\
"Hello",args=[],file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOn\
e.c",line="9"},state="stopped",core="0"}]
865,740 (gdb) 
865,740 67^done
865,740 (gdb) 
865,740 70-thread-info 3
865,740 71-thread-info 4
865,740 68^done,locals=[]
865,740 (gdb) 
865,740 72-thread-info 5
865,740 73-thread-info 6
865,750 74-thread-info 7
865,750 75-thread-info 8
865,830 69^done
865,830 (gdb) 
865,930 70^done
865,930 (gdb) 
866,021 71^done
866,021 (gdb) 
866,111 72^done
866,111 (gdb) 
866,201 73^done
866,211 (gdb) 
866,291 74^done
866,291 (gdb) 
866,381 75^done
866,381 (gdb) 
874,136 76-stack-list-frames --thread 1
874,296 76^done
874,296 (gdb) 
880,747 77-exec-continue --thread 1
880,797 77^running
880,797 *running,thread-id="all"
880,797 (gdb) 
880,817 78-thread-select 1
880,867 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="1",type="dprintf",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x625595e\
6",func="Hello",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOn\
e.c",line="11",thread-groups=["i1"],times="1",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtim\
e-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:11"}
880,977 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="4",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x6255\
9604",func="Hello1",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\te\
stOne.c",line="15",thread-groups=["i1"],times="1",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\ru\
ntime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:15"}
881,008 ~"\nBreakpoint "
881,008 ~"4, Hello1 () at ..\\testOne.c:15\n"
881,008 ~"15\t\tputs(\"Hello World\");\n"
881,008 *stopped,reason="breakpoint-hit",disp="keep",bkptno="4",frame={addr="0x62559604",func="Hello\
1",args=[],file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testOne.c",\
line="15"},thread-id="1",stopped-threads="all",core="0"
881,008 (gdb) 
881,018 79-stack-info-depth --thread 1 11
881,048 78^done
881,048 (gdb) 
881,138 79^done,depth="4"
881,138 (gdb) 
881,138 80-stack-select-frame --thread 1 0
881,148 81-list-thread-groups
881,148 80^done
881,148 (gdb) 
881,148 82-thread-info 1
881,159 83-stack-list-frames --thread 1
881,190 81^done
881,190 (gdb) 
881,250 82^done
881,250 (gdb) 
881,250 83^done
881,250 (gdb) 
905,719 84-exec-continue --thread 1
905,769 84^running
905,769 *running,thread-id="all"
905,769 (gdb) 
905,789 85-thread-select 1
905,849 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="3",type="dprintf",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x6255960\
e",func="Hello1",file="..\\testOne.c",fullname="D:\\Workspace\\Oxygen\\runtime-DevWS\\testOne\\testO\
ne.c",line="17",thread-groups=["i1"],times="1",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runti\
me-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:17"}
906,060 =library-unloaded,id="/home/root/libtestOne.so",target-name="/home/root/libtestOne.so",host-\
name="C:\\myProject\\HW_Libraries_DEBUG\\libtestOne.so",thread-group="i1"
906,060 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="2",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="<PENDI\
NG>",pending="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:9",thread-groups=["\
i1"],times="1",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c\
:9"}
906,060 &"warning: Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library \"C:\\myProject\
\\HW_Libraries_DEBUG\\libtestOne.so\"\n"
906,060 =breakpoint-modified,bkpt={number="4",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="<PENDI\
NG>",pending="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.c:15",thread-groups=[\
"i1"],times="1",original-location="D:\\\\Workspace\\\\Oxygen\\\\runtime-DevWS\\\\testOne\\\\testOne.\
c:15"}
912,313 86-target-detach i1
912,313 ~"\nProgram received signal "
912,313 ~"SIGINT, Interrupt.\n"
912,323 ~"Cannot remove breakpoints because program is no longer writable.\nFurther execution is pro\
bably impossible.\n"
912,353 (gdb) 
912,403 87-stack-info-depth --thread 1 11
912,423 (gdb) 
912,433 =thread-exited,id="29",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="28",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="27",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="26",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="25",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="24",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="23",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="22",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="21",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="20",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="19",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="18",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="17",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="16",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="15",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="14",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="13",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="12",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="11",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="10",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="9",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="8",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="7",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="6",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="5",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="4",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="3",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="2",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"
912,433 =thread-group-exited,id="i1"
912,433 86^done
912,433 (gdb) 
912,433 87^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,434 (gdb) 
912,494 88-stack-list-frames --thread 1 0 10
912,494 88^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,494 (gdb) 
912,494 89-stack-info-depth --thread 1
912,494 89^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,494 (gdb) 
912,494 90-stack-list-frames --thread 1
912,504 90^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,504 (gdb) 
912,514 91-stack-select-frame --thread 1 0
912,514 91^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,514 (gdb) 
912,514 92-stack-list-frames --thread 1 0 0
912,514 93-stack-info-depth --thread 1 2
912,524 92^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,524 (gdb) 
912,524 94-list-thread-groups i1
912,534 93^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,534 (gdb) 
912,534 95-stack-list-frames --thread 1 0 1
912,534 94^done,threads=[]
912,534 (gdb) 
912,534 95^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,534 (gdb) 
912,626 96-list-thread-groups
912,626 97-thread-info 1
912,626 98-list-thread-groups
912,646 96^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process"}]
912,646 (gdb) 
912,656 97^done,threads=[]
912,656 (gdb) 
912,666 98^done,groups=[{id="i1",type="process"}]
912,666 (gdb) 
912,686 99-stack-list-arguments --thread 1 1
912,686 100-stack-list-locals --thread 1 --frame 0 1
912,696 99^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,696 (gdb) 
912,696 101-stack-list-arguments --thread 1 0
912,696 100^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,696 (gdb) 
912,696 102-stack-list-locals --thread 1 --frame 0 0
912,696 101^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,696 (gdb) 
912,696 102^error,msg="Invalid thread id: 1"
912,696 (gdb) 
913,016 103-gdb-exit
913,026 103^exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I figured it out that the format string parameter was passed when I used gdb version 7.12. This feature was not supported in the gdb I was using previously.